# Aplicacao java client server atualizando db mysql e arquivo txt

Tags: java

Obrigado pela atencao, aparentemente esta tudo ok, quando uso localhost funciona. No lado server eu vi algum lugar que tenho que fazer implementacoes, so que nao era bem claro, por exemplo, tenho que ter o CRUD e o DAO tambem do lado server e como faco para controlar as diferentes tabelas do lado server?

Comment: Tente explicar-se melhor, sua pergunta está muito confusa..

Comment: Quando você trabalha cliente servidor em maquinas separadas tem que levar em consideração além do endereço, a porta que você está utilizando, e ver se essa porta não é bloqueada tanto no cliente quanto no servidor. O firewall dos computadores muitas vezes podem estar barrando as conexões da sua aplicação...

Comment: Obrigado pela atencao, aparentemente esta tudo ok, quando uso localhost funciona. No lado server eu vi algum lugar que tenho que fazer implementacoes, so que nao era bem claro, por exemplo, tenho que ter o CRUD e o DAO tambem do lado server e como faco para controlar as diferentes tabelas do lado server?